# width is based on another's element width less to css in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, less

In Bootstrap I found this block of code

```
.site-header {
    padding-left: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
    padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
}
```

this is in LESS, and I was wondering how it would be in CSS3. Can CSS3 just grab another element , take its width, height or whatever, devide it and aply it?

I have no clue how to convert it. I dont think the `grid-gutter` is the parent of `site-header`.

Comment: In this snippet it does not take width from another element. `@grid-gutter-width` is just a constant (= `30px` in default Bootstrap theme), thus this code just sets left/right padding to `15px`. The purpose of this global constant is to be used in different rulesets (but to be customized via single value).

Comment: @seven-phases-max probably in the future standard CSS will have variables, that will have the same functionality

Comment: @vals Thanks, sure I know (they started to promise them more than 10 years ago ;)